# java OOP link between classes (first time programming in java)

Tags: java, oop

I would like to link two classes where the consultant have an ID and I would like to send this ID to the customer so a customer will be assigned to the consultant.

I created a class for the consultant with the ID, name and surname and the same for the customer. I am trying to get the ID from the consultant using the code below

```
Consultant newconsultant = new Consultant(Consultant.getConsultantID());
```

The consultantID is the id of the consultant in the class consultant.I am stuck and I appreciate any help with any information for this issue.

Consultant code:

```
public class Consultant extends Person implements Serializable {
public String ConsultantID;
private String Consfirstname;
private String Conslastname;

Consultant(String consultantID) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

/**
 * @return the ConsultantID
 */
public String getConsultantID() {
    return ConsultantID;
}

/**
 * @param ConsultantID the ConsultantID to set
 */
public void setConsultantID(String ConsultantID) {
    this.ConsultantID = ConsultantID;
}

/**
 * @return the Consfirstname
 */
public String getConsfirstname() {
    return Consfirstname;
}

/**
 * @param Consfirstname the Consfirstname to set
 */
public void setConsfirstname(String Consfirstname) {
    this.Consfirstname = Consfirstname;
}

/**
 * @return the Conslastname
 */
public String getConslastname() {
    return Conslastname;
}

/**
 * @param Conslastname the Conslastname to set
 */
public void setConslastname(String Conslastname) {
    this.Conslastname = Conslastname;
}
```

Customers Code:

```
 public class Customer extends Person implements Serializable {
private String CustomerID;
public String Custfirstname;
public String Custlastname;
private Consultant Consultant;
public String CID;



Consultant newconsultant = new Consultant(Consultant.getConsultantID());





/**
 * @return the CustomerID
 */
public String getCustomerID() {
    return CustomerID;
}

/**
 * @param CustomerID the CustomerID to set
 */
public void setCustomerID(String CustomerID) {
    this.CustomerID = CustomerID;
}

/**
 * @return the Custfirstname
 */
public String getCustfirstname() {
    return Custfirstname;
}

/**
 * @param Custfirstname the Custfirstname to set
 */
public void setCustfirstname(String Custfirstname) {
    this.Custfirstname = Custfirstname;
}

/**
 * @return the Custlastname
 */
public String getCustlastname() {
    return Custlastname;
}

/**
 * @param Custlastname the Custlastname to set
 */
public void setCustlastname(String Custlastname) {
    this.Custlastname = Custlastname;
}

/**
 * @return the Consultant
 */
public Consultant getConsultant() {
    return Consultant;
}

/**
 * @param Consultant the Consultant to set
 */
public void setConsultant(Consultant Consultant) {
    this.Consultant = Consultant;
}

/**
 * @return the CID
 */
public String getCID() {
    return CID;
}

/**
 * @param CID the CID to set
 */
public void setCID(String CID) {
    this.CID = CID;
}
```

There are two forms were the consultant and customers details will be inputted.

Comment: Provide code for both Consultant and Customer Consultant newconsultant = new Consultant(Consultant.getConsultantID()); seems to be wrong.  where is Customer?

Comment: If you're creating a new `Consultant`, from which other `Consultant` are you attempting to get an ID and why?  Structurally the problem here is that you're calling an instance method as thought it were a static method.  But conceptually it's not clear from just this one line of code what you're even trying to do.

Comment: I provided the code with the description

Answer (score 0):

You are calling getConsultatntId in a static way. If your variable is not static you should call the method from a instance of the object (instead of the Class name)

That would look like:

```
Consumer c = new Consumer(1000);
Consultant con = new Consultant(c.getConsumerId());
```

Note that I'm calling getId from 'c' that is a instance of Consumer.

Comment: yes there is where I got stuck, think I am calling the consultantid in the wrong way

Comment: do you want to call getCustomerID() or geConsultantId()? What is the relation between Customer and Consultant?

Comment: I would like to call the consultant ID into the customer using oop. The requirement is that end when inputting a consultant in the consultant form, the id will go to the form of the customer and added in a drop down menu, So when inputting a customer the consultant id can be selected from the drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

In your Customer class are using Consultant class incorrectly.

1. You are trying to access a non-static method in a static way.
2. It is not clear if you have getter and setter methods then why you are trying to create a Consultant instance saperately. This looks to be incrrect in design perspective

What you can do is:

From a another class say MyApplication you can first set Consultant and using the same object you can pass it to Customer.

```
Consultant consultant = new Consultant("123");
consultant.setConsultantID("123");
consultant.setConsfirstname("firstname");
consultant.setConslastname("lastname");
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.setConsultant(consultant);
```

This way your `customer` instance will have a reference to a Consultant instance in it with all the details. This is has-a relationship also called as a composition.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should make your `Consultant` constructor public.  Secondly, you cannot access a non-static method in a static way, meaning you need to make a `public static String getConsultantID()` or something like this:

```
Consultant c = new Consultant("c2418");
Consultant d = new Consultant(c.getConsultantID());
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1: 
To give a customer a consultant id, you would use an instance method instead of a static method:

```
Consultant james = new Consultant("123");
Customer customer1 = new Customer(james.getConsultantId());
```

2:

Consider using an Array or List of Customers in the Consultant class. It would seem more appropriate for a consultant to have multiple customers, rather than a single Consultant to Client relationship. In this way, you create a one-to-many relationship between Consultants and Customers.

Customers would have a reference to their Consultant, and Consultants would have a reference to all of their Customers.

```
public class Consultant extends Person implements Serializable {
public String ConsultantID;
private String Consfirstname;
private String Conslastname;
private ArrayList<Customer> customers;

Consultant(String consultantID) {
    customers = new ArrayList();
}

public boolean addCustomer(Customer c){
customers.add(c);
}
//snipped for brevity
}
```

---

```
public class Customer extends Person implements Serializable {
private String CustomerID;
public String Custfirstname;
public String Custlastname;
public String CID;

Customer(Consultant c){
    CID = c.getConsultantID();
}



//snipped for brevity
}
```

When you create the relationship, you'd create the customer first, assign them a consultant, then add the customer to the Consultant.

```
Consultant kingston = new Consultant("kingston88"); //created elsewhere

Customer jack = new Customer(kingston);             //create customer, give id
kingston.add(jack);                                 //assign customer to consultant
```

Comment: Do I put the code below in the customer?    


Consultant james = new Consultant("123");
    Customer customer1 = new Customer(james.getConsultantId());

Comment: No, you would use code such as that elsewhere in your program, such as the main method.

Comment: Consultant james = new Consultant("123"); and  Customer customer1 = new Customer(james.getConsultantId()); 

initialize two variables named  james and customer1. then you do operations on those variables. 

You could use those variables wherever you present your information, such as a gui thread, or as part of a background thread to save the data to a database.

Comment: Use them in the same places you would use int, char, String, etc.